# #States required not working

Tags: forms

I'm trying to use "#states". When my checkbox is true, I want to make "required" another field. Drupal prints the "required" asterisk but not correctly.

[image]

Here it's the code:

```
  // Return origin.
  $form['search']['return']['return_ori'] = [
    '#attributes'    => [
      'class'       => ['field-autocomplete', 'ret-ori-name'],
      'data-type'   => 'busstop',
      'placeholder' => t('Write your origin', [], ['context' => 'Backend']),
      'required'    => TRUE,
    ],
    '#default_value' => !empty($_GET['return_ori']) ? $_GET['return_ori'] : '',
    '#prefix'        => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-5">',
    '#states'        => [
      'required' => [
        ':input[name="search_return"]' => [
          'checked' => TRUE,
        ],
      ],
    ],
    '#size'          => 40,
    '#suffix'        => '</div>',
    '#title'         => t('Return origin'),
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
  ];
// Return trip.
  $form['search']['search_return'] = [
    '#default_value' => !empty($_GET['search_return']) ? $_GET['search_return'] : FALSE,
    '#prefix'        => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-5">',
    '#suffix'        => '</div></div>',
    '#title'         => t('Search return trip'),
    '#type'          => 'checkbox',
    '#attributes'    => [
      'class' => ['search-return-trip'],
    ],
  ];
```

The submit button has not specific method, so Drupal should handle it. When I press it, the form is sended ignoring my new required field.

Thanks all for help!!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've checked but checkbox's name is "search_return". So that is not the problem. I'm not sure about if "#states" only works in web navigator.

Comment: Yes, `#states` is client side, not server side. You can't use it to validate a required field.

Comment: The JS form API required/optional states currently do not work at all, only visible / hidden. See [Issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2855139) on d..o

Answer (score 2):

In order to toggle the required state you need to target the widget rather than the form element. Answer courtesy of [this very helpful comment](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-11-23/field-states-api-required-hidden#comment-12881635) on Drupal.org.

In your case the code will be something like:

```
$form['search']['return']['return_ori']['widget'][0]['value']['#states']= [
  'required' => [
    'input[name="search_return[value]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the "name" attribute of your search return checkbox by inspecting it within your browser. You may find the name="" isn't actually name="search_return". It may instead be name="search[search_return]" or something similar. So you need to update your states code to whatever the name is